# Linux home folder wrongly mounted after guest addition

Tags: linux, mount, home

I've run into a problem. I'll explain the issue as precise as I can. I run Ubuntu 19.10 on a VirtualBox 6.1.2 version.

The problem looks like this:

When I try to login to my Gnu/Linux account it will appear like it works, but throws me right back to the login screen. The Login credentials are correct, because I can login with "Ubuntu Wayland" with my password and get any sudo rights I need.

AFAIK, I had already this kind of problem in the past, due to a wrongly mounted shared folder between Guest & Host. In that case it was mounted over my home folder. Someone I knew had resolved the problem by mounting my home folder correctly and the shared folder.
I guess it is the same problem this time.

I've tried to install a guest addition to get a bidirectional copy and paste function working.
When I try to navigate to the /home/user/ directory it tells me that it can not read the content & I have no rights to access it.

I am quite new to Gnu/Linux, thus I need a little help to understand how to use `mount` from the terminal.

This is the information I get when I use `mount` in the terminal.

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4047160k,nr_inodes=1011790,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)

tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=815328k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)

cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)

cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)

cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)

cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)

systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=33,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=7894)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/atom_246.snap on /snap/atom/246 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/stickynotes_627.snap on /snap/stickynotes/627 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/zenkit_5.snap on /snap/zenkit/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/telegram-desktop_994.snap on /snap/telegram-desktop/994 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-logs_81.snap on /snap/gnome-logs/81 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8689.snap on /snap/core/8689 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_9.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_544.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/544 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_116.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1440.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-calculator_501.snap on /snap/gnome-calculator/501 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8592.snap on /snap/core/8592 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1397.snap on /snap/vlc/1397 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium-ffmpeg_15.snap on /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/15 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_375.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/375 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-characters_399.snap on /snap/gnome-characters/399 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_110.snap on /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/stickynotes_446.snap on /snap/stickynotes/446 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/inkscape_5874.snap on /snap/inkscape/5874 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1668.snap on /snap/core18/1668 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/telegram-desktop_1038.snap on /snap/telegram-desktop/1038 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_1650.snap on /snap/core18/1650 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/skype_112.snap on /snap/skype/112 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/zenkit_4.snap on /snap/zenkit/4 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/vlc_1049.snap on /snap/vlc/1049 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1353.snap on /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/atom_247.snap on /snap/atom/247 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)

/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_5.snap on /snap/gtk2-common-themes/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/dev/sr0 on /media/linux/VBox_GAs_6.1.2 type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmode=500,fmode=400,uhelper=udisks2)

VMShare on /home/linux type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=998,dmode=0770,fmode=0770,tag=VBoxAutomounter)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=815324k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

This is what it gives me, when I `grep` for `vbox`.

```
root@linux-VirtualBox:~# mount | grep vbox
VMShare on /home/linux type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=998,dmode=0770,fmode=0770,tag=VBoxAutomounter)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please don't post images of text, rather copy paste from the terminal and add it to the post formatting it with the code tool `{}`.

Comment: What is the host OS? also I would not mount on `/home` or `/home/user-name`. It can cause problems. Instead mount in a sub-directory.

Comment: The host OS is Win 7 Ultimate. I had no intentions to mount it on ```/home``` or ```/home/user```. It was after my attempt to install a guest addition.

Comment: Is `/home/linux` your Ubuntu user's home directory? I'd be inclined to put the VBox share under `/media` and use symlinks from `/home/{user}` for the relevant directories/folders.

Comment: Yes, ```/home/linux ``` is my home directory. Sorry, but how do I achieve these two things. How do I move ```VMShare``` which is my shared folder to ```/media```?
Is this necessary to create symlinks to another folder rather than use ```mount``` to get ```/snap``` to mount it on ```/home/linux```?

Comment: There are way too many open question. But the problem you describe is starting a Xsession with the xsession configuration. This is the old way of starting X. In your case this seems to be empty. So X starts, reads this file and finds itself finished and exiting.

The way this works is, that the last command starts the gui and keeps running till you exit. If you exit, this command exits and X knows to exit itself as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you did, so the following is guesswork.

As you say, you might have messed up your home directory. Impossible to do as you, either used root or sudo. Connect as root and look around.  Check the permissions of `/home/user`. Fix with e.g. `chmod u+rwx /home/user`. (I think this is unlikely).

Much more likely is breakage of the startup files for your shell, e.g. `.profile`, `.bashrc`, and similar. Again as root (as you can't  log in, move them to e.g. `.profile.save` and try loging in again. That should work, but your customizations are gone. For each file check e.g. if `. .profile.save` (no, the first '.' is no mistake, it asks to read and execute the contents of the file) works. If yes, move back; if no, edit.

Comment: I've followed your instruction from the first step and it seems not to be the problem.

What I've found out so far is, that all content from my ```/home/user``` is now in a different directory ```/snap```. I still don't know how to get it back to ```/home/user``` and if there are any necessary steps I've to take for /etc/mstab or /etc/fstab.

Comment: Strange... no `/home/user` directory at all? Any other contents of `/snap`? What is the user, group, permissions on `/snap`? You can just `mv /snap /home/user` if it just got moved away and try again... **Keep well clear of the stuff you tried to install.** it looks like it's installer is very badly done (perhaps even malicious).